# styling variables not applied - handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am not sure how to properly apply css to handlebars. Hence I have created the helper function in `js` file to set the variable and while using those variables (contains style attributes and values) the style is not applied. Is there anything missing

**Helper function:**

```
handlebars.registerHelper("setVar", function(varName, varValue, options) {
  options.data.root[varName] = varValue;
});
```

**Inside the handlebars file:**

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template"></script>

{{setVar "tableStyling" "width: 100%;border: 1px solid lightgrey;border-collapse: collapse;"}}
{{setVar "thStyling" "border: 1px solid lightgrey;border-collapse: collapse;padding: 2px 4px;"}}
{{setVar "tdStyling" "border: 1px solid lightgrey;border-collapse: collapse;padding: 2px 4px;"}}
<table style={{tableStyling}}>
    <thead>
        <th style={{thStyling}}>Card Title</th>
        <th style={{thStyling}}>Expiry date</th>
        <th style={{thStyling}}>Target Url</th>
        <th style={{thStyling}}>Content Type</th>
        <th style={{thStyling}}>Entry Url</th>
    </thead>
    {{#each this}}
    <tr>
        <td style={{../tdStyling}}>{{cardTitle}}</td>
        <td style={{../tdStyling}}>{{expiryDate}}</td>
        <td style={{../tdStyling}}>{{targetUrl}}</td>
        <td style={{../tdStyling}}>{{type}}</td>
        <td style={{../tdStyling}}>{{contentfulUrl}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reckon you are missing the **quotes** around the `style` property .

Adding quotes to the table style `<table style="{{tableStyling}}">` fixed the issue for me.

There is an excellent site http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/ where you can try out your templates and helpers.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

1. You can directly write your CSS in template file without using the variable.
2. You can write CSS in variables as a string and print that variable in the template by directly passing it inside the style attribute.

style="{{variableName}}"

to print JSON or HTML in the template you may use triple curly {{{varName}}}